# How to survive out in Siberia, indefinitely?

Tags: apocalypse

In my story there is a worldwide apocalyptic disaster around the 2060s.  And using helicopters, the Soviet Union’s most important military officials and political leaders and scientists, along with some robot protectors, retreat to Siberia, around this area  [image: Screenshot of a map with a spot marked with an X] So, they now have to be able to survive in Siberia indefinitely, and can’t leave without getting lethal radiation doses or getting attacked by mobs of angry Russians. So, how could they get rid of all the problems they will face?

1. Food- it’s bitter cold, so they need to find a way to produce enough food to survive.
2. Power- no one wants to poop out in the woods or live in the dark, so they need a reliable power source that they can replenish easily.

Comment: People have lived in the regions for century.  So I think they will be fine. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chukotka_Autonomous_Okrug

Comment: Oups I meant centuries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stanley Kubrick figured this out 55 years ago.

> "Mr. President, I would not rule out the chance to preserve a nucleus of human specimens. It would be quite easy at the bottom of  some of our deeper mineshafts. The radioactivity would never penetrate a mine some thousands of feet deep. And in a matter of weeks, sufficient improvements in dwelling space could easily be provided."
>
> "How long would you have to stay down there?"
>
> "I would think that uh possibly one hundred years."
>
> "You mean, people could actually stay down there for a hundred years?"
>
> "It would not be difficult mein Fuhrer! Nuclear reactors could, heh... I'm sorry. Mr. President. Nuclear reactors could provide power almost indefinitely. Greenhouses could maintain plant life. Animals could be bred and slaughtered. A quick survey would have to be made of all the available mine sites in the country. But I would guess... that ah, dwelling space for several hundred thousands of our people could easily be provided."
>
> "Well I... I would hate to have to decide who stays up and who goes down."
>
> "Well, that would not be necessary Mr. President. It could easily be accomplished with a computer. And a computer could be set and programmed to accept factors from **youth, health, sexual fertility**, intelligence, and a cross section of necessary skills. Of course it would be absolutely vital that our top government and military men be included to foster and impart the required principles of leadership and tradition. Naturally, they would breed prodigiously, eh? There would be much time, and little to do. But ah with the proper breeding techniques **and a ratio of say, ten females to each male**, I would guess that they could then work their way back to the present gross national product within say, twenty years."

From **Dr Strangelove**, spoken by President Merkin Muffley.